# Shell command in screenrc

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen, screenrc

I'm trying to improve my screen software, so I'll have a lot of questions because there are many answers that I have difficulty to find on internet... Anyway, this one is about a shell command that I would like screen to execute when opening, and it doesn't...

on a new session of screen, I ask screen to open some windows and to name them and to open a file in each of them, and then to split vertically and to open to new empty windows :

```
screen -t name1 vim /path/to/folder/file1.txt
screen -t name2 vim /path/to/folder/file2.txt
screen -t name3 vim /path/to/folder/file3.txt
screen -t name4 vim /path/to/folder/file4.txt
split -v
focus
screen
focus
screen
```

but those files create .file.txt.swp and .file.txt.swo hidden files, as usual, so when my computer shut down and files didn't close properly, when I reopen screen it ask what I must do with the .sw* files... I would like to run first this command `rm /path/to/folder/.*.sw*` so it doesn't ask for the action when opening (".file.txt.swp already exist ! [O]open, [E]dit anyway, [R]ecover, [Q]uit, [A]bandoned")

In the shell `rm path/to/folder/.*.sw*` deletes every swap files as intended, but I can't make it works in .screenrc

This doesn't work :

```
rm /path/to/folder/.*.sw*

screen -t name1 vim /path/to/folder/file1.txt
screen -t name2 vim /path/to/folder/file2.txt
screen -t name3 vim /path/to/folder/file3.txt
screen -t name4 vim /path/to/folder/file4.txt
split -v
focus
screen
focus
screen
```

neither does this :

```
exec rm /path/to/folder/.*.sw*

...
```

nor this :

```
eval 'rm /path/to/folder/.*.sw*'

...
```

or even this :

```
stuff rm /path/to/folder/.*.sw*

...
```

and a lot of other 'blind' tries...

Well I have no idea what I'm doing :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `.screenrc`, the `screen` command takes a *string* which it evaluates itself rather than passing to a shell. So you can't gang multiple commands together so easily...  For example, a config line like this:

```
screen -t test1 touch foo; touch bar
```

would result in three files being touched -- `foo;`, `touch` and `bar`. :)

Instead, you can run a shell interpreter to run multiple commands, including `vim`:

```
screen -t name1 sh -c 'rm /path/to/my/.file1.sw*; vim /path/to/my/file1.txt'
```

The options passed to the `sh` command will be interpreted correctly because within screen, they're all just one option.

If you really plan to do this, you may run in to collisions because `name2` and `name3` etc will generate swap files at the same time as they are being deleted in another window, so you might do this:

```
screen -t name1 sh -c 'rm /path/to/my/.file1.sw*; vim /path/to/my/file1.txt'
screen -t name2 sh -c 'sleep 1; vim /path/to/my/file2.txt'
screen -t name3 sh -c 'sleep 1; vim /path/to/my/file3.txt'
screen -t name4 sh -c 'sleep 1; vim /path/to/my/file4.txt'
```

Note that another alternative might be to tell `vim` not to create swap files at all. Interatively, you can do this with:

```
:set noswapfile
```

To put this on your command line (rather than making it a default for all your `vim` instances), you can use vim's `-n` option, which causes vim to open files with no swap:

```
screen -t name1 vim -n /path/to/my/file1.txt
screen -t name2 vim -n /path/to/my/file2.txt
screen -t name3 vim -n /path/to/my/file3.txt
screen -t name4 vim -n /path/to/my/file4.txt
```

The result will of course be that unsaved changes to your four files will be lost.

One more option might be to move your temporary files to a separate location. For example, if you use `tmpfs`/`shmfs` and your /tmp directory is empty as of every reboot, you might use:

```
screen -t name1 vim --cmd 'set dir=/tmp' /path/to/my/file1.txt
screen -t name2 vim --cmd 'set dir=/tmp' /path/to/my/file2.txt
screen -t name3 vim --cmd 'set dir=/tmp' /path/to/my/file3.txt
screen -t name4 vim --cmd 'set dir=/tmp' /path/to/my/file4.txt
```

Then you can still recover the file if a `vim` instance is killed for some other reason than than the server shutting down.

Comment: awsome ! I'll try all of that, and tell you back if I have trouble, otherwhile thanks a lot !

Comment: My pleasure. And if this solves your issue, please feel free to close the question by clicking the green checkmark to the left of my answer. :)

Comment: I didn't try the temporary file solution, but the two others works perfectly ! I have one more question and one precision about the `sh -c` command :

-the `-c` option is used to override a configuration of the .screenrc file

-and I assume the `sh` command is used to enter a shell command, but it's not clear for me if it's the `shell command` which "is used to create a new shell and override the value of the environment variable $SHELL" ? It may not be important, but the meaning of that is obscure to me...

Comment: So .. not quite. In `sh -c`, the `-c` is an option to the `sh` command, which is your POSIX shell. `man sh` for details on that. We are not overriding anything with this command, we're just running the `sh` command with two arguments, `-c` and a string containing shell commands to run.

Answer (score -1):

When ".file.swp already exist ! [O]open, [E]dit anyway, [R]ecover, [Q]uit, [A]bandoned", you will have more luck removing ".file.swp" then when you try to remove "file.swp", don't you think?

Didn't you notice the **DOT**?

Comment: Regardless of the filename, this does not answer the question.

Comment: Ho yes of course, I'll edit my post, this is not the problem, the command line that I try to run in my .screenrc file work perfectly when I run it in the shell... syntax of the command itself is good, but the way to make it run by screen when opening is a mystery for me

Comment: Also, I don't believe "vim /path/to/my/file1.txt"  would create a file called ".file.swp", but rather ".file1.txt.swp".  Moreover, it would not be in /path/to, but in /path/to/my folder.  Not that I'm trying to answer the question, eh @ghoti?

Comment: If `/path/to` is obviously an example, why would you expect that `file` is not also an example? Was it unclear to you that the OP was asking how to run extra commands in screen?

Comment: To me, it looks as if he's trying to run commands that have no chance of succeeding, BEFORE screen.

Comment: I see. Well, now that he's confirmed (in his comment above) that your initial interpretation was incorrect, will you fix your answer?

Comment: I'm too knew in informatic so I have a big lake of accuracy, and also english is still a little bit difficult for me, and everything you said, Gerard H. Pille, is true, and it's my fault that I havent been precise enough in my post. anyway, on my computer I already noticed all of that, both the .file.**txt**.swp, and the folder path (this one was obvious in the real context, I got confused in the example), and my command line works great when I run it in the shell, I can assure you, I tried it several times !

Comment: In the mean time, ghoti has given you a number of solutions.  The screenrc does not allow you to execute an OS command directly.  That is what you overlooked (and what I didn't know before I checked myself, since I never use screen).